# Excel conditional Hyperlink outputs the Hyperlink for both conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, hyperlink

I think I must be going mad here, what I want to do is to write a simple Excel formula that performs an IF test, and if the result is false I want to hyperlink some text, if it is true I want to display some text which is not hyperlinked.

So for example -

```
=IF(1=1,"1",HYPERLINK("2"))
```

this returns 1 as you would expect, but the 1 is hyperlinked - I only want to hyperlink if the value is 2.

Surely this is possible? Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Man, this limitation of Excel is a shame... (and so is the inability to insert multiple links in a single cell)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because when Excel sees the `HYPERLINK` function in a cell it turns the entire cell into a "followable" cell so that links will work.

The workaround to avoiding the error message "The address of the site is not valid", which occurs when the hyperlink is turned on for the cell but the link has nowhere to go, is to give Excel a link that goes nowhere by referencing the current cell address.

For example:

```
=IF(
    1 = 2,
    HYPERLINK("https://example.com", "Link to example.com"),
    HYPERLINK("#" & ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()), "N/A")
)
```

`ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())` gives a reference to the current cell (e.g. `$A$1`), and `HYPERLINK("#<reference>", ...)` links to the referenced cell.

Comment: My results are a little different.  If I paste your formula into a cell, and then move the mouse directly over the number 1, the cursor changes to a hand.  If I click, I get and "address not valid" message.  If I then change it to IF(1=2... the appearance is the same, but the link works.  If I start with IF(1=2... I get the exact same results.  I never get a blue underlined link.

Comment: Thank you, sending the link to a dummy destination of "" appears to do the trick here.

Comment: note, apply conditional formatting based on the link text to make them not look like links if they're not links. Or moreover, do the reverse: set the links to be black and non-underlined, and then apply conditional formatting to make them blue and underlined if they actually are links.