# Excel makes cell value clickable whenever HYPERLINK() is used in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I'm attempting to use an `IF()` function to conditionally make a cell a hyperlink.

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="http",HYPERLINK(A1,"Link"),IF(A1="","",A1))
```

- If the cell starts with HTTP, it will become a hyperlink.
- If the cell contains nothing ("") it will show nothing.
- If the cell contains another value, it will show that value.

Currently, no matter which scenario above is true, the resulting value displayed in the cell is clickable.

When the formula shows (eg) "Test", I can click that value and I get an error.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? I'm using Office Standard 2013.

Comment: For the record, even just entering the formula in B1, with *no* data in `A1`, the cell is "clickable" for me, Excel 2016.  Would you be open to a VBA macro that does this?

Comment: look at this question, he/she had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363263/excel-conditional-hyperlink-outputs-the-hyperlink-for-both-conditions

Comment: Same thing in 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363263/excel-conditional-hyperlink-outputs-the-hyperlink-for-both-conditions), I think? Summary: when Excel sees the Hyperlink function in the formula, it makes the cell followable, like a hyperlink. You can't prevent that, apparently, but you *can* give the else output a dummy destination like C:\ to avoid the error.

EDIT: Or better, a destination of "", which does nothing when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

According to this site: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/592520-can-i-create-a-formula-using-concatenate.html
there is a add in that can create formulas from strings called Morefunc.

If that works then you should be able to use the following:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1;4)="http";CONCATENATE("=HYPER"; "LINK")&"(A1;Link)";IF(A1="";"";A1))
```

It will return the formula as a string and probably the Morefunc add in can make it a formula.
But I'm not sure about that as I have never used it. There is also some other add in further down mentioned in the thread.[image]