# How to avoid HYPERLINK(link_location,[friendly_name]) adding double quotes to 'link_location' ref_text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm using a Mac and using Excel version 15.18 (as reported in 'About Excel') although the intended use for the final Workbook is both Mac and Win environments.

I'm trying to achieve a 'hover' or 'flyover' facility in Workbook_1 whereby quite a lot of compound data from Workbook_2 can be viewed as a 'hover' or 'flyover' summary. I suspect the best way to achieve this would be via VBA but my VBA (in fact, general programming) skills are very thin (I'm an occasional, recreational coder, although occasionally do things for work, such as this) and although a VBA option is perhaps something I could investigate in time, I need something a little quicker in the short term, and in any case, the rest of my Workbook is virtually there.

I'm seeking a mechanism (if one exists) for avoiding HYPERLINK(link_location,[friendly_name]) adding double quotes to 'link_location' when it is a reference to a cell that contains text.

I know that...

```
=HYPERLINK("[/Users/joc25/Desktop/Report_Audio_Current_171017.xlsx]Sheet1!R10C2","W")
```

... will open the secondary Workbook and highlight cell R10C2 in that Workbook, displaying 'W' in the cell in the current Workbook.

However, through curious experimentation, I stumbled upon the observation that...

```
=HYPERLINK([Report_Audio_Current_171017.xlsx]Sheet1!R10C2,"X")
```

... although it won't actually open the link (not an issue to me) will (if the described file is open, which it will be) will display the contents of the R10C2 cell (in the secondary Workbook) as a 'hover' summary (in the current Workbook), which is exactly what I'm trying to achieve! However, this only works if the above mutation/abuse of the HYPERLINK function is written into a Workbook cell explicitly and this is not possible for me. I need the 'link_location' to be dynamic based on user selection in other cells.

So, if a cell in Workbook_1 contains...

```
=HYPERLINK(Sheet_Loc_Short&"R10C2","Y")
```

... where range 'Sheet_Loc_Short' contains...

```
="["&R35C49&R36C49&R37C49&"]Sheet1!"
```

... where the individual cell references contain individual text that serve to build up the full file name and, when computed, effectively translates the file location and path to (for example)...

```
[Report_Audio_Current_171017.xlsx]Sheet1!R10C2
```

.. the eventual function becomes...

```
=HYPERLINK("[Report_Audio_Current_171017.xlsx]Sheet1!R10C2","Z")
```

... which doesn't work in the 'hacked' way described above.

Note that in reality, the target file will change (date) and the target cell / range will change (via some match based on varying criteria), but for this exercise, I've endeavoured to keep this simple and refer to the specific problem I face with the construction of the HYPERLINK function.

Is there any way to avoid the quotation / speech marks being added and yield the 'hover' / 'flyover' functionality that I can when entering the function and file name explicitly into a cell?

First question here, so please go easy on me!!

Many thanks.

Comment: does `indirect` work for you here?

Comment: Thanks @ForwardEd - I'd previously tried INDIRECT and it hadn't worked for me. But, spurned on by your suggestion, I tried it once more just now on a simple sample and realised I had been applying it incorrectly! I was previously applying the INDIRECT function only around the 'Sheet_Loc_Short' 'ref text', when I should have been wrapping the whole text construct. I'll add it into the full formula when I next get chance later and confirm all is good. Many thanks!

Comment: Since you are working with HYPERLINK as a formula, you may be interested in [this oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695579/formula-information-displaying-correctly-but-link-information-is-not) that I encountered when I was working with the formula

Comment: Thanks @ForwardEd - that's useful. Whilst discussing HYPERLINK, I also fell foul of another 'oddity' - that being that if HYPERLINK is mentioned anywhere within a formula, the output is formatted as a HYPERLINK. In my case, I want 'test = true' => result = HYPERLINK , whilst 'test = false' => result = Plain Text. The latter was always being formatted as a HYPERLINK. After several hours of trying to debug a rather complex formula, I eventually discovered [this useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363263/excel-conditional-hyperlink-outputs-the-hyperlink-for-both-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## INDIRECT()

This formula should be your friend in this situation.  It turns text addresses into cell references excel will actually listen to.  The main caveat here is that `INDIRECT` will only work with open workbooks.  Which if I read correctly will not be an issue for you, just something to keep in mind.